# How to have javascript multi array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp-classic

I need multidimensional array, like this:

```
var myarray = [ ['username1', 10], ['username2', 20] ];
```

This array I need In (classical) ASP page (Default.asp), on other ASP page (generate.asp) I have MS SQL commands. So Idea for AJAX sending string from *generate.asp* to *Default.asp* is:

```
username1,10;username2,20
```

And in Default.asp build array someting like that:

```
var data="username1,10;username2,20";
data.split(';').each(function(){
//current ITEM. data.split(',')
new Array(item[0], item[1])
});
```

Please help me with syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to use JSON, like this:

```
var myarray = [{username1 : 10}, {username2 : 20}]
```

Comment: I can't help you there. But anyway, you can create your JSON as a string (in ASP) and then use JSON.parse("[{username1 : 10}, {username2 : 20}]") in JS.